# Haskell: Getting a value out of an RVar in Data.Random

Tags: haskell, random, monads

How do I write a function with a type signature like:

```
mySample :: StdGen -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

in terms of

```
sample :: Int -> [a] -> RVar [a]
```

where sample is defined in [Data.Random.Extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random-extras/0.17/doc/html/Data-Random-Extras.html#1)? Here, sample is a function which returns a random sublist from the given list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random-fu/latest/doc/html/Data-Random.html#t%3aRVar), this should work:

```haskell
mySample :: StdGen -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
mySample g n xs = fst $ sampleState (sample n xs) g
```

However, I get overlapping instance errors when trying to compile it. I got this to compile, though:

```haskell
mySample :: StdGen -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
mySample g n xs = evalState (runRVar (sample n xs) StdRandom) g
```